# google chrome crashs on startup with invalid opcode

Tags: linux, google-chrome, opcode, turnkeylinux.org

i have the problem that the google chrome 54.0.2840.100-1 chrashed on my linux (TurnKey LAMP Stack 14.0). TurnKey LAMP Stack 14.0 is based on Debian Jessie and runs in a VMWare virtualisation.

Here the error messages:

```
Nov 23 11:29:37 test kernel: [ 3697.087259] traps: chrome[3794] trap invalid opcode ip:7f4e1a21b699 sp:7ffc8ae3b910 error:0 in chrome[7f4e1914e000+6430000]
Nov 23 11:29:37 test kernel: [ 3697.088518] traps: chrome[3785] trap invalid opcode ip:7fda6a67202d sp:7fff579ef600 error:0 in chrome[7fda6967d000+6430000]
```

I found some older hints about supporting SSE2. But my VM support this:

```
flags: fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts nopl tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes hypervisor lahf_lm ida arat epb pln pts dtherm
```

I found and try an older version of chrome (42.0.2311.90) from here: http://google-chrome.en.uptodown.com/ubuntu/old and it works without crashing.

I have also tried a fresh installed ubuntu 16.04 on the same machine and the same conditions (VMware) and it's also working. So the problem seems to be a system or driver problem or something like that.

Can anybody help to get the current version running?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I tried now chromium and it' running fine with parameter --no-sandbox:

```
chromium --no-sandbox
```

Comment: That shuts off most of the security.